# Java BufferedInputStream Progress Bar

Tags: java, swing, download, jprogressbar, bufferedinputstream

I'm having a slight issue getting a `JProgressBar` to show the status of an HTTP download.
The progress bar is working, however it fills up too quickly and eventually overshoots the max value by quite an amount, as shown below:

```
public void test(InputStream stream, File location) {  
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(stream);  
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(location);  
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(file);  
    int i;  
    int bytesDownloaded = 0;  
    while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {  
        bytesDownloaded += i;  
        out.write(i);  
        System.out.println("Bytes downloaded: " + bytesDownloaded + " out of " + len);  
        update(bytesDownloaded);  
    }
}
```

The issue is that `bytesDownloaded` ends up being much greater than len at the end of the file, is `in.read()` actually returning the bytes it's upto in the file or some other value? I'm assuming the former from the Java 7 API, however it does not line up with my findings.

I am testing this snippet on a 2.69MB File.
This is the output from the println statement (the last few lines)

> Bytes downloaded: 371525502 out of 2821490
>      Bytes downloaded: 371525526 out of 2821490
>      Bytes downloaded: 371525631 out of 2821490
>      Bytes downloaded: 371525788 out of 2821490
>      Bytes downloaded: 371526028 out of 2821490
>      Bytes downloaded: 371526222 out of 2821490
>      Bytes downloaded: 371526442 out of 2821490
>      Bytes downloaded: 371526697 out of 2821490
>      Bytes downloaded: 371526914 out of 2821490

Now I know that `2821490` is the correct byte value of 2.69MB, so then my question remains, why is the `read()` function of the BufferedInputStream showing the end of file read bytes as `371526914`, if this really was bytes then that equals around 350MB which the file is obviously not!

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you not using BufferedInputStream#read(byte[] b, int off, int len) ? It's more performant, because you read several bytes at the same time and it behaves the way you are expecting by returning the number of bytes read.

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann: my thoughts exactly. It's like using a shotgun to hunt sparrows.

Comment: Didn't really look too much into that option since I thought I read somewhere that it may block to fill up the buffer. Guess it was wrong, Just looked over the API for it and i'll implement that now. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out, after `i = in.read()`  executes the `i` variable holds the byte representation of the data one byte into the file, and so on for each loop iteration. So it is not a count of bytes read, it is the actual data of one byte.

I changed my `bytesDownloaded += i;` to `bytesDownloaded++;` and that gave me the correct result both in the debug output as well as the progress bar.

Comment: You could have discovered all that from the Javadoc, instead of just guessing about it.

Answer (score 2):

Just interpose a [javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html).